# Minimum value of $\frac{\sin x}{4} + \frac{1}{\sin x}$? $x \in (0, \pi/2)$

Tags: trigonometry, maxima-minima, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

> **Question.** What is the minimum value of
> $$ \frac{\sin x}{4} + \frac{1}{\sin x}$$
> subject to $x \in (0, \pi/2)$?

Applying AM-GM inequality, we get

$$ \frac{\sin x}{4} + \frac{1}{\sin x} \geq 1. $$

However, for the expression to be equal to $1$, $\sin x$ must be $2$, which is not possible. Moreover, on plotting the graph, the minimum value is $\frac{5}{4}$.

Please explain.

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another way to solve the exercise without using derivatives.

For any $\,x\in\left(0,\dfrac{\pi}2\right]\,$ it results that

$\begin{align}\dfrac{\sin x}4+\dfrac1{\sin x}&=\sin x+\dfrac1{\sin x}-\dfrac34\sin x=\\[3pt]&=\left(\!\sqrt{\sin x}-\dfrac1{\sqrt{\sin x}}\!\right)^{\!2}\!+2-\dfrac34\sin x\geqslant\\[3pt]&\geqslant2-\dfrac34\sin x\geqslant2-\dfrac34=\dfrac54\;.\end{align}$

Moreover ,

$\dfrac{\sin x}4+\dfrac1{\sin x}=\dfrac54\iff\sin x=1\iff x=\dfrac{\pi}2\;.$

Consequently, the minimum value of $\,\dfrac{\sin x}4+\dfrac1{\sin x}\,$ subject to $\,x\in\left(0,\dfrac{\pi}2\right]\,$ is $\,\dfrac54\,,\,$ but the function $\,\dfrac{\sin x}4+\dfrac1{\sin x}\,$ does not have a minimum on the interval $\left(0,\dfrac{\pi}2\right),\,$ in fact it only has the infimum (the greatest lower bound) which is $\,\dfrac54\,.$

Answer (score 2):

Write $f(x) = \dfrac x4 + \dfrac 1x$. Then $f'(x) = \dfrac 14 - \dfrac 1{x^2}$ which is negative when $0 < x < 2$.

Thus $f$ is decreasing on the interval $(0,1]$, so its minimum value on that interval occurs at $x=1$ and the minimum value of $f$ is $f(1) = \dfrac 54$.

Finally observe $x \in (0,\pi/2)$ implies $\sin x \in (0,1)$.

Comment: If you do derivatives, why not take directly the derivative of the given expression?

Comment: Right, that makes sense, but why did AM-GM not work in this scenario?

Comment: @Tirthik The AM-GM inequality is still true in your problem since both $\frac{sin(x)}{4}$ and $\frac{1}{sin(x)}$ are positive, and the minimum of the function as you noticed is $5/4$ which is greater than $1$, but equality can only happen when  $\frac{sin(x)}{4}=\frac{1}{sin(x)}$ , which as you mentioned cannot happen for real values of $x$.

Comment: AM-GM only holds with equality the numbers involved are equal, i.e. $\sqrt{xy} = \frac{x+y}{2}$ if and only if $x=y$. You found an inequality, but there never was a guarantee that a tighter inequality could not be derived.

Comment: Beware: $\frac{5}{4}$ *would be* the minimum value of $f(x):=\frac{\sin x}{4}+\frac{4}{\sin x}$ if $\pi/2\in(0,\pi/2)$. Strictly speaking, $f(x)$ does not have a minimum in the interval $(0,\pi/2)$.

Comment: @Gonçalo that wasn't claimed in the answer.